# PHP adds spaces after Post

Tags: php

my code is:

```
<table width="100%" class="table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><h4>Cagayan de Oro</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Temperature</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $_SESSION['Timez'][0]; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="number" maxlength="2" placeholder="Temp" name="Temp1" style="width: 60px;" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['post'])) echo $_POST['Temp1'];?>"></td>

        <p align="right">
           <input type="submit" name ="post" value="Assimilate" class="btn-primary">
        </p>

    </form>
```

My problem is that after clicking the submit button, the value of my $_POST['Temp1'] would display leading spaces.

How do I fix this?

Comment: use `trim(_POST['Temp1'])` to remove spaces from your post value

Comment: use `trim()` for trimming the spaces..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[trim()](https://www.php.net/trim) removes spaces from your string.

so use it your code while printing like this

`trim($_POST['Temp1'])`

instead of using

`$_POST['Temp1']`

Comment: so its going to be <td align="center"><input type="number" maxlength="2" placeholder="Temp" name="Temp1" style="width: 60px;" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['post'])) echo trim($_POST['Temp1']);?>"> ??

Comment: thanks. but i don't understand why it added 34 spaces.

Comment: Please close your input tag, that might also cause you this problem

Comment: Isn't there a closing tag for input?

Comment: there is no explicit closing tag for input.use close tag like this `<input type="number" maxlength="2" placeholder="Temp" name="Temp1" style="width: 60px;" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['post'])) echo $_POST['Temp1'];?>"/> `

Comment: Note i have added `/` at end of input tag

Comment: oh, i see. trim function works. adding a closing to the tag to the input doesn't omit the spaces.

Comment: ok.I am not sure about why it adds spaces. May be some one having ideas might post there help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

> $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

to remove all the extra spaces from the string.